# Error in console when including the library

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm starting on learning EmberJS and I see this error in the console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'proto' of undefined ember-1.0.pre.min.js:17
```

It seems that just by including the library I get that error. Does anyone have any idea why I get that ?

**EDIT : Added HTML Markup**

```
<!doctype html>

  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=2">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
      {{#view App.MyView}}
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
      {{/view}}
    </script>

    <!-- The missing protocol means that it will match the current protocol, either http or https. If running locally, we use the local jQuery. -->
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.pre.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Also there's this JS in the `app.js` file :

```
var App = Em.Application.create();

App.MyView = Em.View.extend({
  mouseDown: function() {
  window.alert("hello world!");
}
});
```

but it has been removed and all the templating part from the HTML as well, and I still got the same error (:

Comment: Very difficult to say what is going on without more context...

Comment: @sly7_7 - that's the thing ... there's nothing else going one, just an simple index.html file in which the jquery and handlebars libs are included (:

Comment: Could you try with the non minified version and see what is undefined ?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Unable to find view at path 'App.MyView' ember-1.0.pre.js:43`

Comment: Ahh, this is more understandable :) could you post your code ?

Comment: I have no code, do you mean the unminified version of EmberJS ?

Comment: Ok, you have to declare the App as a global (removing `var`).

Comment: I see ... by the way, why most of the times the variables are global and not defined with `var` ? is it something EmberJS specific or required ?

Comment: I think handlebars try to get the "context" from global. but the only global variable you should have, is the App namespace itself. After that all should be define from this namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Ember Documentation](http://emberjs.com/documentation/):

> Every Ember app should have an instance of Ember.Application. This
>   object will serve as the globally-accessible namespace for all of the
>   other classes and instances in your app

The key here is "global". Here's an example of an application:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
```

Your problem is the `var`-keyword on your `Application.create`. Remove that and add `Window` to make the error disappear.